# Is there a way to specify the entire first and last columns in auto-fit CSS grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I would like a css grid that looks like this:

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│         │         │         │         │         │
│         │  item   │  item   │  item   │         │
│         │         │         │         │         │
│         ├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤         │
│         │         │         │         │         │
│firstcol │  item   │  item   │  item   │ lastcol │
│         │         │         │         │         │
│         ├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤         │
│         │         │         │         │         │
│         │  item   │  item   │  item   │         │
│         │         │         │         │         │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

that can resize responsively to:

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│         │         │         │         │
│         │  item   │  item   │         │
│         │         │         │         │
│         ├─────────┼─────────┤         │
│         │         │         │         │
│         │  item   │  item   │         │
│         │         │         │         │
│         ├─────────┼─────────┤         │
│         │         │         │         │
│firstcol │  item   │  item   │ lastcol │
│         │         │         │         │
│         ├─────────┼─────────┤         │
│         │         │         │         │
│         │  item   │  item   │         │
│         │         │         │         │
│         ├─────────┼─────────┤         │
│         │         │         │         │
│         │  item   │         │         │
│         │         │         │         │
└─────────┴─────────┘         └─────────┘
```

or narrower or wider, etc.

For the containing DIV, I've tried a repeats...

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px repeat( auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr) ) 100px;
  grid-auto-flow: row; /* or column really ;-) - either is ok */
}
```

...and I've tried media queries:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 100px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 1fr 100px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 1fr 1fr 100px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 100px;
  }
}
```

For the containers, I've tried:

```css
.firstcol {
  grid-column: 1 / span 1 ;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}

.lastcol {
  grid-column: -2 / -1 ;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}
```

... as well as variations on areas. I can't seem to get the first and last column areas specified dynamically.

Am I wrong? Is `grid-row: 1 / -1;` *not* meant to mean the 1st row to the last row, or ?

Comment: it can be done by a mixture of 3 `div`s. the one in the center should be `flex box`

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you want, but can somehow demonstrate it...

please run the snippet in full screen mode.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        html,
        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #parent {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 100px auto 100px;
        }

        #firstcol {
            width: 100px;
            background-color: aquamarine;
        }

        #centercol {
            display: flex;
            background-color: bisque;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            align-content: flex-start;
            animation-name: anim;
            animation-timing-function: linear;
            animation-duration: 10s;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
        }

        #lastcol {
            width: 100px;
            background-color: aquamarine;
        }

        .item {
            background-color: chocolate;
            display: inline;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }

        @keyframes anim {
            from {
                height: 100px;
            }
            to {
                height: 800px;
            }
        }
    </style>

    <body>
        <div id="parent">
            <div id="firstcol">FIRST</div>
            <div id="centercol">
                <div class="item">1</div>
                <div class="item">2</div>
                <div class="item">3</div>
                <div class="item">4</div>
                <div class="item">5</div>
                <div class="item">6</div>
                <div class="item">7</div>
                <div class="item">8</div>
                <div class="item">9</div>
                <div class="item">10</div>
            </div>
            <div id="lastcol">LAST</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I went with, with apols to MMD's idea about flex box.

The key was this:

`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));`

The minmax(150px, 1fr) fills in the row with elements of min size, but lets them stretch to fill the row.

```css
.entry {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto 100px;
}

.stats {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.firstcol {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid lightsalmon;
}

.lastcol {
  margin: 0 padding: 0;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
  <div class="firstcol">Row #1</div>
  <div class="stats">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
    <div class="item">D</div>
    <div class="item">E</div>
    <div class="item">F</div>
    <div class="item">G</div>
    <div class="item">H</div>
    <div class="item">I</div>
  </div>
  <div class="lastcol">
    <button>Action</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="firstcol">Row #2</div>
  <div class="stats">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
    <div class="item">D</div>
    <div class="item">E</div>
    <div class="item">F</div>
    <div class="item">G</div>
    <div class="item">H</div>
    <div class="item">I</div>
  </div>
  <div class="lastcol">
    <button>Action</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="firstcol">Row #3</div>
  <div class="stats">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
    <div class="item">D</div>
    <div class="item">E</div>
    <div class="item">F</div>
    <div class="item">G</div>
    <div class="item">H</div>
    <div class="item">I</div>
  </div>
  <div class="lastcol">
    <button>Action</button>
  </div>
</div>
```